# Android application interacting with a server

Tags: android, database, database-connection

Ok so, I know the question is pretty much google-able and I did google it and found out a few answers ,so I am not asking this question knowing completly nothing.

So, I have an application (Cannot specify much about what it does or is or so...) and I need to get some data from a database.

As far as I know, the Volley is the best way to go ,but I am still looking for more details.

Could anyone tell me which is the best way to go?

NOTE: I am NOT looking for code,I am looking for methods.A name would sufice ,as I can do the digging myself.Eventually links to documentations would be awesome, but again, I can find documentations.I just need to know which is the fastest way and the most optimized.

Comment: As you already know, there are probably 200 different ways to do this. Each better or worse than the other in some perspective. So, let's start with defining what "best" means in your case. If you're  talking about server side implementation and looking into Volley, I'd say you're somewhat off track.

Comment: Well, the point is that I don't really know what I need for the volley connection.I mean, can I use a normal Apache server for the testing part of the application? That meaning I have installed mysql and php (phpmyadmin) on the host I will use.

This is where I need a bit of guidance.If I go with Volley for the app side ,what do I need on the server side?

Comment: Also ,sorry for the slow answers ,I am sort of bussy and I cannot stay focused here ,like I would normally do when I ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like there are two different aspects to your application:

1. Sending out the HTTP requests from your client- i.e. your android app
2. Processing and sending the response to these requests on the server side, by setting up a web service

Looks like you have part 1 figured out. Note that, volley is a library, similar to android HTTP library, but optimized for faster networking.

For part 2, unless you're planning to use embedded database like sqlite, you'd need to learn about writing web services to provide database access. 
[Spring Data JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) is one of the many ways to do it.

I hear [Parse](https://parse.com/) is great too, but not free.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information.
I will wait untill tomorrow to get more answers...if I won't get any other ,I will check it as the correct one.Anyways, it is what I  needed.Although, I will just check the rabbitMQ.I am not sure how it works but I hear it's fast!Also ,yes I knew VOlley is a library.

Comment: Alright man...is not all that i am looking for but your answer was pretty much decent and the reason is not what I am looking for is that I did not specify everything and didn't give details.So Ima check your answers.Cheers and happy programming!